# Enforce FirstOrDefault to return null

Tags: c#, entity

I need to return null, if an element is not found in a list, but it returns a empty guid.

```
mappedTypes.Where(x => x.ReferenceId == new Guid("1a087b71-638c-4f3c-b1cf-3b0438c181c0")).Select(x=>x.MappingId).FirstOrDefault()
```

This query just returns '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' - and I want to return null - or a single guid-value if it exists.

Comment: You can use `?.` to check for null like this: `mappedTypes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ReferenceId ==new Guid("1a087b71-638c-4f3c-b1cf-3b0438c181c0"))?.MappingId;`

Comment: FirstOrDefault() is causing it. Default for Guid is an empty guid. Your query expects at least one record returned but there is no records it can return at all, so it goes for default. It's what you asked it to do actually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might select it with casting to `Guid?`:

```
mappedTypes.Where(x => x.ReferenceId == new Guid("1a087b71-638c-4f3c-b1cf-3b0438c181c0"))
           .Select(x => (Guid?) x.MappingId)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

See also:
[Nullable types (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)

Comment: Just for clarification: the reason why this works is because it casts the generic type hold by the `IQueryable` returned by `.Select` to a nullable, and nullables have a default value null. If `FirstOrDefault` cannot find a "first", it then takes the default of a `Guid?` which is null.